# Help me! App crashes when selecting the check box

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Please look at my below code.

Is there any leaks or issues in my code since my application getting crashed when i select the check box.

Looking for any help...

Thanks!.

```
// checkbox at normal state
copyMailCheckbox = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 150, 220,120 ,40 )]; 
UIImage *normalStateImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.jpg"]; 
[copyMailCheckbox setImage:normalStateImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[normalStateImage release]; 

// checkbox at selected state UIImage
UIImage *checkedStateImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.jpg"]; 
[copyMailCheckbox setImage:checkedStateImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];   [checkedStateImage release]; 

// checkbox at highlighted state UIImage
UIImage *highlightedStateImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-pressed.jpg"]; 
[copyMailCheckbox setImage:highlightedStateImg forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];   [highlightedStateImg release];
[self addSubview:copyMailCheckbox];
[copyMailCheckbox release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an allocation error here:

```
UIImage *normalStateImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.jpg"]; 
[copyMailCheckbox setImage:normalStateImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[normalStateImage release];
```

This UIImage object normalStateImage doesn't need you to call release on it. Remember the rule of allocations, if you call init, retain or copy, then you release the object. Otherwise, you should not do it because you don't have ownership on it.

PD:Also check please what sudo rm -rf is pointing.

Comment: This is most likely your problem if that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
*checkedStateImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.jpg"];
```

and this:

```
*highlightedStateImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-pressed.jpg"];
```

You're creating an unknown pointer or something.  I don't know how that got past the compiler warning, but you need to specify `UIImage`, for example...

```
   UIImage *highlightedStateImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-pressed.jpg"];
```

Also, I'd suggest that you use `.png` for images.  Although it's not required, it speeds up some image processing operations and is the generally recommended format for images.

**Edit:** It looks like your code was a typo, so please disregard this.

Comment: no that was a typo...can you pls look at the code and provide me some guidence on my issue...